# How to do unit test of whenComplete block of code in Java?

Tags: java, testing

CompletionStage.whenComplete() block of code is run and its results are ignored even if it throws an exception, but in my test case, I want it to break based on the exception.
How do I test it? I'm able to simulate assertion-based exception from internal code but the exception is ignored and hence test cases do not fail.

```
return orderService.newOrder(order, request)                      
    .whenComplete((__, throwable) -> {                                                 
        if (throwable == null) {                               
            eventPublisher.publishEvent(orderSummary.getOrderId());
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you pls add some code to show us an example? thx

Comment: Here publishEvent failure is ignored so any exception from that won't get propagated and hence such exception testing can't be done here. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Thread.sleep is one way to test this flow but not a nice way to test.